# Line numbers in \captionof

Tags: captions, lineno

I would like to prepare a dcument of class `article` with line numbers. Calling `\linenumbers` numbers the lines within the text as expected. However, I would also like to number the lines of captions within the `\captionof` function. So far, only the last line within the caption is numbered. Calling `\internallinenumbers` before `\captionof` has no effect. (I guess as I do not have a float.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.6cm, right=2.9cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\section{Some section}
Some text

\section{Figure legends}
\captionof{figure}{This should be a figure legend occupying several lines to demonstrate the problem. I will just write some text, don't pay attention to it. It does not make much sense.}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `\internallinenumbers` *before* `\caption` you have to use it *inside* the mandatory `\caption` argument:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.6cm, right=2.9cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\section{Some section}
Some text

\section{Figure legends}
\captionof{figure}[{This should be a figure legend occupying several lines to
  demonstrate the problem. I will just write some text, don't pay attention to
  it. It does not make much sense.}]{\internallinenumbers This should be a figure legend occupying several lines to demonstrate the problem. I will just write some text, don't pay attention to it. It does not make much sense.}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Repeating the mandatory argument without `\internallinenumbers` as optional argument is needed to avoid writing (the expansion of) `\internallinenumbers` to the `lof` file, which is used to generate the list of figures.

You could even place the `\internallinenumbers` automatically to the mandatory argument only:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.6cm, right=2.9cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\captioncaptionof\captionof
  \RenewDocumentCommand\captionof{mO{#3}m}{%
    \captioncaptionof{#1}[{#2}]{\internallinenumbers#3}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\section{Some section}
Some text

\section{Figure legends}
\captionof{figure}{This should be a figure legend occupying several lines to demonstrate the problem. I will just write some text, don't pay attention to it. It does not make much sense.}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{document}
```

Note: This suggestion would not work, if you'd put `\captionof` inside a box or minipage. In this case the box/minipage would get it's own line number. So you would have to switch off line numbering before the box and reactivate them after it:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.6cm, right=2.9cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\captioncaptionof\captionof
  \RenewDocumentCommand\captionof{mO{#3}m}{%
    \captioncaptionof{#1}[{#2}]{\internallinenumbers#3}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\section{Some section}
Some text

\section{Figure legends}
\nolinenumbers
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{This should be a figure legend occupying several lines to demonstrate the problem. I will just write some text, don't pay attention to it. It does not make much sense.}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{minipage}

\linenumbers
Text of next paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The first option has worked for me. I am not sure whether something speaks against not repeating the caption text, but  `\captionof{figure}[{figure}]{\internallinenumbers My caption text.}` works fine for me. I also tried redefining `\captionof` as specified. However, this sadly causes errors such as `You can't use macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. \begin{document}`. I am fairly new to Latex, so I am not sure why that would be.

Comment: @Mareike Even before fixing the second argument number, I wasn't able to see such an error message with any of my examples. I've tested with TeX Live 2020, 2021, 2022 and 2023. Older TeX Live would need package `xparse`, but IMHO it is difficult to support older LaTeX versions, so you should use at least (the latest version of) TeX Live 2020. I would recommend to use an up-to-date TeX distribution.